# Chemfig polymer brackets without compiling twice

Tags: tikz-pgf, compiling, brackets, chemfig

I'm working on the following picture:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
    \schemestart
    n \quad \chemfig{C(-[3]H)(-[5]H)=C(-[1]H)(-[7]H)}
    \arrow
    \chemfig{-[@{op,.60}]C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-[@{cl,0.40}]}
    \schemestop
    \polymerdelim[delimiters ={[]}, height = 30pt, depth = 30pt, indice = \!\!n]{op}{cl}
\end{document}
```

It seems that I need to compile the document twice in order for the brackets to appear. According to the Chemfig manual, some things seem to require a feature called "picture remembering", and I think it is probably related to this. I assume that the location for the brackets is saved on the first run and used on the second run.

Chemfig manual says (not about brackets but about electron movements):

> It is assumed that the viewer supports “picture remembering” and that the compilation is done twice.

My questions are:

1. Why do brackets require compiling twice when most other features do not?
2. How can I create polymer brackets without having to compile twice?
3. What does it mean for a viewer to support “picture remembering”? Does this refer to the pdf viewer?

I would like to avoid compiling twice, because I'm compiling a lot of pictures on a server and if I would set it to compile twice, that would double the compile time for all pictures. That's why I would prefer a solution that would require compiling only once.

Comment: What software do you use to compile your file? I use TeXStudio and it does both builds with just one "F5" command.

Comment: 1. It needs to know the size of the molecule (first run) to place correctly sized brackets (second run), 2. One solution would be, to put the code into a standalone file (as you already did for the MWE) and insert the resulting PDF into the main document.

Comment: I'm building with pdflatex on a server, and I'm only building standalone images that are embedded on a web page i.e. they are not embedded in a main document. I could insert it as an image, but that's not an ideal solution.